# How to add trailng icon in radio list tile flutter

Tags: flutter, radiobuttonlist

**I am using** the `RadioListTile` for displaying the dynamic data with radio button in flutter,but **I want** to display the same list with an trailing icon for editing the list data.

- Can you please help me how to do that in flutter?

  ```
               RadioListTile(
                          groupValue: _currentIndex,
                          title: Text(
  //                                          addres["address_1"],
                            addres["firstname"] +
                                addres["lastname"] +
                                addres["address_1"] +
                                addres["city"] +
                                addres["country"],
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            maxLines: 3,
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.0),
                          ),
                          value: int.parse(addres["address_id"]),
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            setState(() {
                              _currentIndex = val;
                              Navigator.push(
                                  context,
                                  MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => PickanAddresspage(selected_address: addres['address_id'],)));
                            });
                          },

                        )
  ```

Comment: check [this link](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RadioListTile-class.html#material.RadioListTile.3)

Comment: i am adding the code which i have tried ..in that i want to add icon button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In title , you can user Row to wrap Text and Icon 
Use Expanded and flex to control width you need 
code snippet

```
title: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Text(
              "firstname" +
                  "lastname" +
                  "address_1" +
                  "city" +
                  "country234123412344523523452542345234523523542345245234523452345235234523452345245234523452452542",
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
              maxLines: 3,
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.0),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: InkWell(
              child: Icon(
                Icons.audiotrack,
                color: Colors.green,
                size: 30.0,
              ),
            ),
          )
        ],
      )
```

[image]

full test code

```
// Flutter code sample for

// ![RadioListTile sample](https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/material/radio_list_tile.png)
//
// This widget shows a pair of radio buttons that control the `_character`
// field. The field is of the type `SingingCharacter`, an enum.

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

/// This Widget is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: MyStatefulWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

enum SingingCharacter { lafayette, jefferson }

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  MyStatefulWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyStatefulWidgetState createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  SingingCharacter _character = SingingCharacter.lafayette;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        RadioListTile<SingingCharacter>(
          title: const Text('Lafayette'),
          value: SingingCharacter.lafayette,
          groupValue: _character,
          onChanged: (SingingCharacter value) {
            setState(() {
              _character = value;
            });
          },
        ),
        RadioListTile<SingingCharacter>(
          title: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Text(
                  "firstname" +
                      "lastname" +
                      "address_1" +
                      "city" +
                      "country234123412344523523452542345234523523542345245234523452345235234523452345245234523452452542",
                  overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                  maxLines: 3,
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16.0),
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                child: InkWell(
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.audiotrack,
                    color: Colors.green,
                    size: 30.0,
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
          value: SingingCharacter.jefferson,
          groupValue: _character,
          onChanged: (SingingCharacter value) {
            setState(() {
              _character = value;
            });
          },
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```